# what does "X = (!X ? 8 : X)" mean in javascript?

Tags: javascript, ternary-operator

I recently read a javascript code online and want to convert it to C#. When encountered this line of code, I had no idea what it does: X = (!X ? 8 : X). Please explain.

Comment: have a look at the [ternary operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/be21c7hw(v=vs.94).aspx)

Comment: i'd prefer `if(!x) x=8;` The ternary doesn't save anything in this particular case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It checks whether or not `X` is false (contains either 0, empty string, null, or undefined). If it is, the line assigns 8 to `X`, otherwise `X` retains its original value.

Answer (score 2):

It sets the `X` var to 8 if `!X` is true (so if `X` is false). Otherwise, X keep the same value.

So, if X is an empty string, the `false` boolean or the 0 number (I might forget some values but well you understand), it'll be set to 8, else it'll keep its original values. It's the same as:

```
if(!X) { X = 8 }
```